# Animate a collectionview swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autoresize

Hello I am trying to animate a CollectionView. It need to change the position x and his width.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 500, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 700)
})
```

But the problem is the image in the cell doesn't resize, and i think the cell too.
Have you a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionViewCell size is independent from the frame of the parrent UICollectionView.

maybe you can actually "zoom in" on the layer

```
    var transformation = CGAffineTransform.identity
    let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 2, y: 2)
    let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    transformation = scale.concatenating(translate)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, animations: {
        self.collectionView.transform = transformation
    })
```

Maybe *invalidateLayout* call can help you.
Also are you using customflowlayout

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple custom flow layout.
2. Assign this flow layout class to your collection view in storyboard.

   ```
   class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
       override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
          return true
       }
   }
   ```

   And it's better to animate constraints than frame. To do so:
3. Make outlet of width and leading constraints.
4. Change their constant inside UIView animation block.
5. Don't forget to call self.layoutIfNeeded() in the end of animations block.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have a problem now I have a bad effect when the animations start. 
The image inside the cells widens and narrows.

Comment: @jimmy-gonçalves can you provide some more info about how do you build cell? how cell size changing?

Comment: I put my actual code for show you, my cell are actually set with the method in UICollectionFlowLayout which is size for item at.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller, if you are using storyboard, connect `UICollectionviewFlowLayout` (`collectionViewFlowLayout` in my example) using IBOutlet, collection view width constraint (`collectionViewWidth` in my example) as IBOutlet and `UICollectionView` as IBOutlet (`collectionView` in my example). You can change the collection view frame and cells simultaneously with the following:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5, execute: {
  self.width = 400
  self.height = 400
  self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.collectionViewFlowLayout.invalidateLayout()
    self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.collectionViewFlowLayout, animated: true)
  }, completion: { _ in })
})

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5, execute: {
  self.collectionViewWidth.constant = 50
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut,
                             animations: self.view.layoutIfNeeded, completion: nil)
})
```

You need to declare `width` and `height` var as class properties with initial value of 100 for example. This is then changed in the above code. It is made possible because of the below implementation. Note this requires you adopt the protocol `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  }
```